# give a 'toastr' popup its own options

Tags: toastr

I've got toastr popups all through my app. They may or may not be custom-configured in my app.

I am using Angular, though I'm not sure this is actually Angular-toastr.

I want to make this one toastr have different options (position, sticky, close-button), - even from other toastrs on the same page.

Is there a way to specify options for a single toaster instance, so that others don't inherit its options?

Everywhere in my app, I just call

```
toastr.success("Go team!");
```

and it uses whatever defaults are already set.

Here, I want to something like this:

```
var bigToast = new toastr;
bigToast.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
     "tapToDismiss": true
}
bigToast.success("Yah! REALLY go team!")
```

That way, only bigToast is affected. 'course it's not a constructor, so it fails.

I'm trying this:

```
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
    "tapToDismiss": true
}
toastr.success(":)");
```

and even that has no effect, so I'm clearly implementing it wrong. I see the :) but none of the options have been picked up.

As far as I can tell, the toastr object is empty. This:

```
toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-top-center"
```

throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'positionClass' of undefined
```

I am clearly a dunce, since this apparently so simple, virtually no working examples are necessary.

These config forms show *what* you can do but now *how* you actually do it.

https://foxandxss.github.io/angular-toastr/

http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Comment: Technical note: form will not accept **toastr** spelling as valid. Refuses to submit. Must put in quotes: **'toastr'**.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the options as  third argument.

```
toastr.success(":)","",{
"closeButton": true,
"positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
"tapToDismiss": true});
```

The second argument is the title, keep that blank if you don't want to show a title.